# How do I fix my Discord music bot's command error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, botframework, audio-player

I am programming a music player bot for discord and it's not working. I expect the bot to join a voice channel, instantaneously play a song, and then iterate through a playlist of songs (announcing the name of each song when it starts).

Below is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import time

#playlist of songs containing .wav files, artist names and length of song
playlist = {'Foriegn_Accent.wav':['Plague of Grackles (aka @borlip)', 128],'Go_Harder.wav':['ac', 234]}

#sets prefix for every discord command
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

#logs bot into discord
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('The bot is now ready')
  print('--------------------')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx): #user says /join and bot joins voice channel and plays music
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect() #joins voice channel
    for song in playlist: #loop through songs in playlist
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(song) #reads wav file
        player = voice.play(source) #plays audio in voice channel
        song = song.replace('_'," ")[:3] #song name
        artist = playlist[song][0] #artist name
        length = playlist[song][1] #length of song in seconds
        await ctx.send(f'Playing {song} by {artist}') #sends message in text channel
        time.sleep(length) #waits for song to finish before next iteration
```

When I run the code, the bot joins the channel, plays the first song in the playlist and does not fulfill any further tasks. It gives me this error message:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'For'
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
```

And after some time, the last line changes to this message:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TimeoutError:
```

What does this error message mean, and how can I get my bot to fulfill the rest of its tasks?